# Practical example for the identity $r(r-1) \binom{m}{r} =m(m-1) \binom{m-2}{r-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I see that many a times we use the result

> $$r(r-1) \binom{m}{r} =m(m-1) \binom{m-2}{r-2}.$$

I know it is easy to prove the result, but how to relate it to a practical problem, i.e. how do I look at it as a physical example?

I would highly appreciate if any one can help me relate this result to a practical situation.

I know it may be easy but I am just starting up.

Comment: I assume that by $~^mC_r$ you mean $\binom{m}{r}$, the binomial coefficient "$m$ choose $r$" the number of ways to choose $r$ objects out of $m$ distinct objects where order doesn't matter.  It sounds like you are asking for a combinatorial proof of the identity $r(r-1)\binom{m}{r}=m(m-1)\binom{m-2}{r-2}$.  Is that correct?

Comment: "how do I look at it as a physical example?" I am sorry, I do not know what you mean. Combinations are very practical though. are you satisfied with saying it's the number of groups of size $r$ from a group of size $m$ with a captain and a co-captain selected from the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for a combinatorial proof of the identity $m(m-1)\binom{m-2}{r-2}=r(r-1)\binom{m}{r}$

---

Given $m$ people, we wish to count how many ways we can form a committee with a chairman, a vice-chairman, and $r-2$ lower ranking committee members (*for a total of $r$ committee members if you include the chair and vice-chair*).  We do this by counting in two different methods.

**Method 1:**

- Pick the chairman from the overall pool of people.  $m$ choices
- Pick the vice-chairman from the remaining pool of people. $m-1$ choices
- Pick $r-2$ additional people to serve on the committee.  $\binom{m-2}{r-2}$ choices

This gives a total of $m(m-1)\binom{m-2}{r-2}$ ways in which we can accomplish this.

**Method 2:**

- Pick the $r$ people for the committee.  $\binom{m}{r}$ choices
- From those people selected for the committee, pick who will be the chairperson: $r$ choices
- From those people selected for the committee remaining, pick who will be the vice-chairperson: $r-1$ choices

This gives a total of $r(r-1)\binom{m}{r}$ ways in which we can accomplish this.

As both methods give a count for the same scenario, by fundamental principles of counting, the two expressions must be equal.

Comment: "Assuming you are looking for a combinatorial proof of the identity" I'm afraid this assumption is almost certainly wrong, but I have no idea what the OP actually wants.